# Error while trying to upload image to facebook

Tags: java, android, android-facebook

I am trying to upload image to Facebook using facebook api.
But getting error please find the code below.
I am unable to find out the error. I tried debugging it but am unable to understand the error looking at the log cat. Please help experts. Thanks in advance.

```
public void postImageonWall(Bitmap bmpImg) {
        byte[] data = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmpImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();
        Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");          
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        try {
            facebook.request(params);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

Log Cat:
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:50)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Util.encodeUrl(Util.java:85)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:145)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:717)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:633)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.example.dragview.DragActivity.postImageonWall(DragActivity.java:458)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.example.dragview.DragActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DragActivity.java:428)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:244)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:165)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:130)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:300)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 05:55:52.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1220):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The NullPointerException that you get occurs when you declare a variable but did not create an object. Can you check if you have initialized the variable `facebook`

Comment: `private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);` yes i did it.